# SoapFault - faultcode and request soap with library ksoap2

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap, android-ksoap2

I try to call request from the library ksoap2 in android, but receives the error in android studio:

```
I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
W/System.err: SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Client' faultstring: 'Message part {http://rogal.ws.pl/map/thumbnail}GetThumbnail was not recognized.  (Does it exist in service WSDL?)' faultactor: 'null' detail: null
W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.parseBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:136)
W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:140)
W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:129)
W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.parseResponse(HttpTransportSE.java:304)
W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:276)
W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:118)
W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:113)
W/System.err:     at rogal.sieciowyws.MainActivity.requestSoap(MainActivity.java:67)
W/System.err:     at rogal.sieciowyws.MainActivity.testConnect(MainActivity.java:46)
W/System.err:     at rogal.sieciowyws.MainActivity.access$100(MainActivity.java:19)
W/System.err:     at rogal.sieciowyws.MainActivity$LoginTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:94)
W/System.err:     at rogal.sieciowyws.MainActivity$LoginTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:83)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:307)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:246)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

my android code looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String SOAP_URL = "http://92e7a7ca.ngrok.io/api/map?wsdl";
    public static final String NAMESPACE = "http://rogal.ws.pl/map/MapService/";
    public static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetThumbnail";

    TextView text;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        Button signin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new RequestTask().execute();
            }
        });

    }

    private void req() {
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = new PropertyInfo();
        propertyInfo.setName("Name");
        propertyInfo.setValue("hello");
        requestSoap(propertyInfo);
    }

    public void requestSoap(PropertyInfo... propertyInfos) {
        String mResponse = "";
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        for (PropertyInfo propertyInfo : propertyInfos) {
            request.addProperty(propertyInfo);
        }

        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_URL);
        ht.debug = true;
        try {
            ht.call("", envelope);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            mResponse = envelope.getResponse().toString();
            text.setText(mResponse);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            System.out.println();
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(final Void... unused) {

            System.out.println();
            req();
            System.out.println();

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

I've added permissions in the manifest file:

web service in java: [here](https://ufile.io/2ece7)

wsdl: [here](https://ufile.io/ed08f)

schema xsd: [here](https://ufile.io/3a4a6)

I check the operation of the web service tool SoapUI and working properly.

I did not notice a fault that could cause this exception.

I will be grateful for your help

Comment: The error message tells you what you need to know - there is no method "GetThumbnail" defined in the WSDL.  Look at the WSDL.  There is a method named "Thumbnail".

Comment: both give the same exception